# after setState, want to give data to ReactTable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

there are parent component and child component(ReactTable).

Parent component has `state` value which is `jsonResult`.

Every time the `state.jsonResult` changes, I want to re-render `<ReactTable />`.

> Despite `jsonResult` exists, it always return `blank Table`.
>
> How can I set `<ReactTable/>` data dynamically?

I get 'data' from `<DropZone />`component.

```
class Request extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {sampletext: 'aaaa'};
        this.state = {
            files: [],
            jsonResult: ''
          };
      
    }

    render()
    {
        const {classes} = this.props;
        //this.setState({sampletext: 'bbbb'});
        

        return (
            <FusePageSimple
                classes={{
                    root: classes.layoutRoot
                }}
                header={
                    <div className="p-24"><h4>IMK request 시연 페이지</h4></div>
                }
                contentToolbar={
                    <div className="px-24"><h4>호출 시나리오</h4></div>
                }
                content={
                    <div>
                        <div className="p-24">
                            <h2>Token Value</h2>
                            <Input value={'Bearer faa1e3b28de23d0a9811df77c21bf990'}/>
                            {/* <FileUpload /> */}
                        </div>
                        <div className="p-24">
                            <h2>File Upload</h2>
                           
                            <div>
                                <DropZone
                                    getJson={(jsonResult,valueCount) => {
                                    this.setState({ jsonResult, valueCount });
                                }} 
                                >
                                    <p>under 100mb csv file only</p>
                                </DropZone>
                              
                            </div>
                                
                        </div>
                        <div className="p-24">
                            <h2>Get File Text</h2>
                            <div>
                                {/* <TextField 
                                    value={this.state.sampletext}
                                    multiline
                                    rows="20"
                                    className="{classes.textField} w-full"
                                    margin="none"
                                    variant="filled"
                                    />  */}
                                <div> 
                                {/* {this.state.jsonResult ? (
                                    <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state.jsonResult)}</div>
                                ) : null} */}
                                {console.log(this.state.jsonResult)}
                                {(this.state.jsonResult) ? (
                                <ReactTable
                                    data={this.state.jsonResult} 
                                    columns={dataTableColumns}
                                    minRows={0} />) 
                                : 
                                null}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="p-24 flex">
                            <div className="flex1">
                                {/* <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className="{classes.button} w-full" onClick={this.handleSearch}>
                                   API call Button
                                </Button>    */}
                                <RequestButton data={this.state.jsonResult} count={this.state.valueCount}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            />
        )
    }
}
```

I print `state.data` on console. it did. but not printed to ReactTable.
[image]

> Demo: [stackblitz.com/github/ohoroyoi/test-dropzone](https://stackblitz.com/github/ohoroyoi/test-dropzone)

Comment: Are you sure this is valid?  `this.state = {sampletext: 'aaaa'};
        this.state = {
            files: [],
            jsonResult: ''
          };`  I mean won't the latter one override the previous one (talking about duplicate declaration of `this.state` ?

Comment: Can you create stackblitz link with sample data?

Comment: @Justcode I'm sorry not all exactly same. because my react theme is paid. so except ReactTable style, others are same. https://stackblitz.com/github/ohoroyoi/test-dropzone here you can see

Comment: @Justcode you can see test csv file in my github repo /src...

Answer (score 0):

this problem was I missed accessor in table columns.

```
const dataTableColumns = [
    {
        Header: 'request_id',
        headerClassName: 'table-color-1'
    },
    {
        Header: 'product_name',
        headerClassName: 'table-color-2'
    },
    {
        Header: 'model_name',
        headerClassName: 'table-color-3'
    },
    {
        Header: 'spec',
        headerClassName: 'table-color-4'
    },
    {
        Header: 'manufacturer',
        headerClassName: 'table-color-5'
    },
    {
        Header: 'customer_company_id',
        headerClassName: 'table-color-6'
    },
    {
        Header: 'workplace_id',
        headerClassName: 'table-color-7'
    }

]
```

there was no accessor, so ReactTable couldn't mapping json array to table.

after this, it works.

```
const dataTableColumns = [
    {
        Header: 'request_id',
        accessor: 'request_id',
        headerClassName: 'table-color-1'
    },
    {
        Header: 'product_name',
        accessor: 'product_name',
        headerClassName: 'table-color-2'
    },
    {
        Header: 'model_name',
        accessor: 'model_name',
        headerClassName: 'table-color-3'
    },
    {
        Header: 'spec',
        accessor: 'spec',
        headerClassName: 'table-color-4'
    },
    {
        Header: 'manufacturer',
        accessor: 'manufacturer',
        headerClassName: 'table-color-5'
    },
    {
        Header: 'customer_company_id',
        accessor: 'customer_company_id',
        headerClassName: 'table-color-6'
    },
    {
        Header: 'workplace_id',
        accessor: 'workplace_id',
        headerClassName: 'table-color-7'
    }

]
```

this is so newbie problem, hope it helps somebody...

Answer (score 0):

In ReactTable component use getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) or componentWillReceiveProps to get the updated data from the previous state. Here ReactTable got the initial empty string and doesn't get the updated value.